# When installing php from source configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>

Tags: dpkg, php, make, openssl

I am trying to build php from source but ./configure gives error

configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's

my `openssl version` returns

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2f  28 Jan 2016
```

and `which openssl`

```
/home/nexusstar/.linuxbrew/bin/openssl
```

and `dpkg -S /usr/include/openssl/conf.h`

```
libssl-dev:amd64: /usr/include/openssl/conf.h
```

and `ll /usr/include/openssl/ | grep "evp.h"`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  52K дек  4 15:59 evp.h
```

I try to pass ./configure with and without sudo and try all of the bellow and few more:

```
--with-openssl=/usr 
--with-openssl=/usr/include
--with-openssl=/usr/include/openssl
--with-openssl=/home/nexusstar/.linuxbrew/bin/openssl
--with-openssl=/home/nexusstar/.linuxbrew/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2f/include/openssl
```

But it always returns:

`configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>`

or

`configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL`

I do not know What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I getting same error when trying to install php version using `phpbrew` even all libs install but unfortunately not work my case, can you please tell me how you did resolve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find openssl](http://askubuntu.com/questions/211038/cant-find-openssl)

Answer (score 0):

If you install all openssl related library on system even getting error like `configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>` and `configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL` then try to set below variable.

```
$ OPENSSL_LIBDIR=/usr/include/openssl
$ OPENSSL_INCDIR=/usr/include/openssl
```